# Redirect after POST using plug_cowboy (2.0)

Tags: elixir, plug

I got a simple Plug post handler like this

```
post "/some/url" do
   # do something
   # render(something)
end
```

…but I would like to redirect somehow to another `get` handler, instead of rendering html.

How to do this using plug_cowboy 2.0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no magic: you have to send `HTTP 302` response:

```
conn
|> put_resp_header("location", url)
|> send_resp(conn.status || 302, "text/html", body)
```

Phoenix [does the same](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/v1.4.9/lib/phoenix/controller.ex#L392-L400).